# AngularJS : How to pas multiple parameters in route

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am building an application using AngularJs.
I suddenly stuck in a routing where I want to send multiple data in route but its not woking.
Her is my route :

```
.state('/filter-list', {
    url: "/search/india/:data?",
    views : {
        "" : {
            templateUrl:"/filter/filter-list.html",
            controller: 'filterListCtrl',
            controllerAs:'vm',
            authenticated: true
        }
    },

    resolve: {
        loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('/filter-list'); // Resolve promise and load before view
        }]
    }
})
```

I want to send data like this:
/search/india/state/city/hotel-name

But if I try to send this, it is redirected my application to home page.
only '/search/india/new-delhi' is working.
Can someone help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the params in your route like this:

```
.state('/filter-list', {
    url: "/search/india",
    params: {
              state: '',
              city: '',
              hotel-name: ''
            }
    ...
    }
```

and in your controller you can use `$state.go()` method like this:

```
$state.go("/filter-list", {
    state: 'your-chosen-state',
    city: 'your-chosen-city',
    hotel-name: 'your-chosen-hotel'
});
```

and inside your controller you can capture the params from:

```
 const state = $stateParams.state;
 const city = $stateParams.city;
 const hotel = $stateParams.hotel-name;
```